# Requesting the ability to star an answer, and just not the question

Tags: feature-request, answers, bookmarks, popular-question

This is especially true for the IT-based stack exchanges, where the questions are all pertinent to an issue the searcher has. However, many times these popular questions have pages of answers, and the answers at the top aren't necessarily pertinent, even if the user has marked the question as answered.

Would it be possible to implement a feature to star an answer, and not the just the question? So that if we run into the problem again, we don't have to browse through pages of answers.